# Specifying location of gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've done some searching online and tried a few things with no luck.

I compiled Ruby 1.9.1 on a Mac that had previously been running 1.8.7.

How can I now either reinstall the gems, or point. Rubygems installs to the old location, but 1.9.1 is looking elsewhere. I've tried making a 1.9.1 (and 1.9) gems directory as a symlink to the old directory, but that doesn't seem to work. I've tried setting GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH but again no luck.

How can I find out where the current version of ruby is searching for gems at runtime, and alter it? And/or, how can I instruct rubygems to install gems where the latest version is looking for the gems.

Answer (score 1):

You should either use a rvm, as was suggested, or install ruby 1.9.2 to /opt/ruby (configure --prefix=/opt/ruby --enable-shared) or /usr/local or /usr/local/ruby. Then put this path first in your PATH, before everything else. You'll have to reinstall gems anyway, as some of them are incompatible (built for 1.8.7).

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to install [rvm](https://rvm.io) and let it wrangle your Ruby versions and gems for you.

Also, you should probably upgrade to 1.9.2, as it's much more stable. 1.9.1 is basically a buggy development version of 1.9.2.